# RS232 from a Decatur Radar to a PC

Tags: serial-port

I just got a [Decatur SI-2](http://ghawgood.com/pdf/radars/si2.pdf) it communicates via RS232 through a DB9 connector.

So I went out to BestBuy and got a [Dynex™ 16" USB PDA/Serial Adapter Cable](http://www.dynexproducts.com/products/cables-cords-adapters/DX-UBDB9.html). Since I couldn't get it to work on my Macbook Pro I have downloaded the driver on a HP.

I was planing on using my Mac and to just type in:

To find the port:

```
ls -l /dev/tty.*
```

Then open a screen from there:

```
screen /dev/tty.usbmodem411 9600,8N1
```

But since I'm using a pc what do I need to do? Can I use command prompt? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will create a virtual comport which should appear in your device manager under serial ports. Right-click on the device, select properties and the port number and settings are in there. To talk to it you could use software like hyperterm or realterm. Hyperterm comes with older windows versions but it's pretty basic. [Realterm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/) is a free download.